# Posfix - deny sender emails containing specific text in username

Tags: block, postfix-mta, rule, spam-prevention, mail-sender

Postfix, Debian. I'm receiving spam and I'm not sure how can block it, because spammers uses different mail address everytime.

For example:
mike.newsletter30@gmail.com
mike.sfsd4f564s6df45ds@gmail.com
mike.newsletter30u@gmail.com

etc.

I have setup sender access file, so I can block mails from specific servers like this:

mike.newsletter30u@gmail.com REJECT

But it's not enough. I need to setup more specific rule, for example all senders containing 'mike.' should be blocked in this case.

Unfortunatelly, rule like this:
mike. REJECT

doesn't work. I've searched google and postfix docs I still can't figure out how to do this. Is this even possible?

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 Years and no clarification :S
Note that it is a regular expression, Using:

```
/^(F|f)rom: *mike*@gmail.com/
```

won't work because you are thinking of * as a wildcard, regex uses * to match preceding character 0 or more times, the dot (.) is used to match any character, so the regex to match fsdghfsdjmike84329@gmail.com should be something like

```
/^(F|f)rom: .*mike.*@gmail.com/
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the file is imported with `hash` or similar and only works if imported with `regexp`

Answer (score 2):

First ensure that you have enabled header checks in your main.cf

```
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

Then add a matching rule to your checks for example:

```
/^(F|f)rom: mike.*@gmail.com/ REJECT JUNK is not allowed by this server
```

Finally restart/reload postfix to active changes.

Comment: This works, but not entirely. I've tried to block text inside, for example mails like fsdghfsdjmike84329@gmail.com. So I used syntax like this: '/^(F|f)rom: *mike*@gmail.com/ REJECT JUNK is not allowed by this server' - but it doesn't work. How to block mails with substring I provided?

Comment: @user1209216 Don't use * by itself. " *" means zero or more spaces and "e*" means zero or more letter "e". Dot means any character. So put .* to get any one or more character. So what you are looking for would be 

/^(F|f)rom: .*mike.*@gmail.com/ REJECT JUNK is not allowed by this server